# jQuery to move element depending on screen size

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a better solution to move a couple of element depending on the screen size. I thought my code was okay. It worked perfectly when I resized the browser window on the desktop, but then when I tested on a smaller device like a mobile phone, the element didn't move, because there was no resize event.

Then I tested this code after the document ready line, but it didn't work at all:

```
var window-width = $(window).width();

if(window-width < 800) {

    $( ".intro-content p" ).prependTo( ".intro-bottom" );
    $( ".intro-content h1" ).prependTo( ".intro-bottom" );

}
```

This is the first code that I seek a solution to improve:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var win = $(window).width();
responsiveAction(win);
});

function responsiveAction(width) {

if(width < 800) {

    $( ".intro-content p" ).prependTo( ".intro-bottom" );
    $( ".intro-content h1" ).prependTo( ".intro-bottom" );

}

if(width > 800) {

    $( ".intro-bottom h1" ).appendTo( ".intro-content" );
    $( ".intro-bottom p" ).appendTo( ".intro-content" );
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an alternative for you: Put the element in **both** places in your markup, and use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to show/hide it in the relevant location. Look, ma, no JavaScript!

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* Smaller screen, hide location 2 */
  .location2 {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 601px) {
  /* Larger screen, hide location 1 */
  .location1 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="target location1">I'm in location 1, I'll disappear if the viewing area is &gt; 600px wide</div>
<div>...stuff here...</div>
<div>...stuff here...</div>
<div>...stuff here...</div>
<div>...stuff here...</div>
<div>...stuff here...</div>
<div class="target location2">I'm in location 2, I'll disappear if the viewing area is &lt;= 600px wide</div>
```

---

From your comment:

> I don't want to write the headline and text twice or do I only need to write it once and then use jQuery

Let's say you write it once, and then when the page is being loaded (you've used `ready`, which is okay; I just make sure `script` tags are at the end of the page instead), just copy the content once:

```
$(function() {
    setup(".intro-content p");
    setup(".intro-content h1");

    function setup(selector) {
        var content = $(selector);
        content.clone().addClass("bottom").prependTo(".intro-bottom");
        content.addClass("content");
    }
});
```

Then apply the media queries to `.content` and `.bottom`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I use CSS to display the new element to hold the <h1> and <p> tag. I'm doing a WordPress theme, and I guess the need to update the headline and text add two places it's not the best solution. Any other ideas?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: *"I guess the need to update the headline and text add two places it's not the best solution"* Why not? You already use jQuery, so `$(".target").text("new content")` will update both of them.

Comment: than you prepend `.intro-bottom` you can use it in media query for `.intro-content`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you mean T.J. Could you be kind to develop you code a little bit more? Since it's a CMS I don't want to write the headline and text twice or do I only need to write it once and then use jQuery?!

Comment: @3D-kreativ: I've added to the answer to address that comment.

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting, but you write that the script must be at the end of the page. This isn't possible. WordPress load all scripts within the <head> tag. Would it not work if it's in the <head> tag?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: I *didn't* write that it has to be at the end of the page. I said *"you've used `ready`, which is okay; I just make sure script tags are at the end of the page instead"* So if Wordpress really requires that the scripts are in `head` (really? in 2015? having trouble believing that), just keep using `ready`. (The code example uses `ready`, through the shortcut.)

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution and works well

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    moveButtons();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    moveButtons();
});

function moveButtons() {
    var win = $(window).width();
    if (win > 800) {
        $('#positionTop').append($('#myContent'));  // move to div with id positionTop
    } else {
        $('#positionDown').append($('#myContent'));  // move to div with id positionDown
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this solution and works well

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    moveButtons();
});

 $(window).resize(function() {
    moveButtons();
});

 function moveButtons() {
    var win = $(window).width();
    if (win > 800) {
        $('#positionTop').append($('#myContent'));  // move to div with id positionTop
    } else {
        $('#positionDown').append($('#myContent'));  // move to div with id positionDown
    }
};
```